# How to remove/fix some artifacts from generated image while keeping most parts of the image intact?

Tags: image, image-generation, stable-diffusion, text-to-image, clipdrop

I generated some images using this prompt.

> white knight with wings holding sword and shield

There are many results from that but let's say I like this one.

[image: white knight with wings holding sword and shield]

However, it has some flaws in it that I think they are called artifacts, but feel free to correct me if I am wrong. I want to keep most of this image intact while make it regenerating/editing only some parts of the images. For example, I want to just fix the hands in this image so that it looks a bit less weird.

How can I do that? I have tried regenerating using the same prompt hoping to see this character comes up again with good hands. No hope.

I used ClipDrop/Stable Diffusion to generate the image. I prefer to to do in here without getting the image to other tools. However, if that is not possible, feel free to give solutions that involve other tools.

I just want to fix the hands.

Comment: Related question for fixing hands, limbs, fingers: [How can I effectively create a prompt to generate realistic limbs and fingers?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/16/36)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Inpainting** is a technique that allows you to mask out a specific area for the model to modify while keeping the rest of the image unchanged. This can be used in multiple ways:

- If the masked region starts from its existing contents, a low denoising strength can be used to slightly tweak it
- If the masked region restarts from random noise, something entirely new matching a prompt can be generated in the space
- If the masked region starts from an average of surrounding unmasked colours, a masked object can be removed from the image

The first would be most appropriate for fixing hands, but unfortunately ClipDrop only seems to currently allow the latter - via ["Cleanup"](https://clipdrop.co/cleanup):

[image: Before/after of ClipDrop's cleanup tool used on the right hand of the knight in the question's image. The hand gets removed.]

---

Allowing for other tools, [Automatic1111's Web UI](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui) gives more control over inpainting.

In the "img2img" section, select the "Inpaint" tab, load in your image, and scribble to mask out the area you want to inpaint:

[image: "Inpaint" tab of Automatic1111's Web UI, with knight's hand masked out.]

You can then specify that the region should start from its current content when inpainting:

[image: Masked content option, with "original" selected.]

A lower denoising strength will stay closer to the existing contents. Your prompt should describe the full image, unless you set "Inpaint area" to "Only masked", in which case you should only describe the masked area.

Example generation:

[image: Before/after of inpainting with Stable Diffusion in Automatic1111's Web UI on the right hand of the knight in the question's image. An altered hand is generated.]

Documentation on further inpainting options: https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/Features#inpainting