# How can I effectively create a prompt to generate realistic limbs and fingers using Leonardo.ai?

Tags: image-generation, prompt-design, negative-prompt, leonardo.ai

Image generation - midjourney, leonardo, etc - are not good at generating realistic hands. It is common to see hands with extra fingers or in weird shapes.

As an example, a basic prompt like this on Leonardo:

> kylian mbappé hyper realistic shooting on a soccer field wearing a real madrid jersey

Generates:

[image]

Another example with the prompt:

> Hyper realistic Real human image, image of a woman facing her boss and receiving a small Amount of money with her hands from her bosses hands , they must be dressed in 1915 fashion style with woman wearing a gown and the man a shirt and a trousers high quality image. 8k, studio resolution, image must be colorful hyper realistic , zoomed image , no deformed figure, HD , only a man and a woman no more, black and white image

and a negative prompt of

> Deformed hands deformed bottles , hands in the background. Deformed body , jam packed images of people, blurred faces and eyes, disfigured noses and face , vacant bed, empty bed, deformed people lying on the bed 3D , Anime, 4 people in the background, A woman and a woman shaking

Generates

[image]

---

How can prompts be adjusted to reflect a realistic number of limbs, fingers and body position using Leonardo.ai?

Comment: Related question for an approach broader than "1-time generation": [How to remove/fix some artifacts from generated image while keeping most parts of the image intact?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/8/36)

Comment: This question looks like that needs more focus. It's OK to mention that many GenAI tools have the same problem, but the question should focus on using a single GenAI tool.

Comment: @Wicket I had called out using Leonardo in the opening, but did clarify the question at the end to limit it to Leonardo.

Comment: @Wicket I think a question asking about _general principles_ could be okay, _if_ such an answer exists.

Comment: Well, you do ask for a "Deformed body" in the second prompt. Maybe their definition is a bit broader than we know of?

Comment: @Mast-onstrike That's a negative prompt. The generator should NOT include information in that prompt.

Comment: Ah, you're correct. Does that work when the actual prompt mentions "no deformed figure"? As far as I understand now, the negatives should be reserved for the negative prompt. Is it possible this confuses the generator? Does the issue still occur when you remove negative prompts from the prompt?

Answer (score 6):

#### Adjusting the prompt

The positive prompt can be roughly thought of as a caption the image is likely to have. Terms like "no deformed figure" would be [unusual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCEJR.png) descriptions for actually-normal images, and may have the opposite effect to what you intend. Below I compare "Charlie Chaplin" to "Charlie Chaplin, not jumping" with SDXL 0.9:

[image: Generated image of Charlie Chaplin, showing counter-productive effect of "not jumping" caption]

Putting instead "deformed" in the negative prompt shouldn't hurt, but may have limited impact. The reason a negative prompt like "watermark" successfully discourages the model from inventing watermarks is because the generation of watermarks is due to the model deliberately creating one, and the model has an association between the word and the visual pattern. On the other *hand*, deformed hands are almost always (unless generating zombies) going to be an artefact of the model's capabilities rather than a choice it can trivially avoid, or even know to associate with "deformed".

For similar reasons, "must be colorful hyper realistic" should be rephrased into a possible caption rather than an instruction.

These changes should make a small positive impact, but with current models solely relying on the text prompt can only go so far and it'd still likely take generating a large number of images until the hands happens to look correct. There are however other techniques and tweaks that could help more significantly:

#### Inpainting

Once you're happy with most of the image, inpainting would allow you to focus on iterating specific areas such as the hands.

The frontend you're using, Leonardo.ai, appears to allow this in "AI Canvas". Result of using the eraser on the extra pair of arms and then inpainting:

[image: Leonardo.ai inpainting]

You can also start from the existing deformed hands or paint/photobash in some basic hands, mask out that region, then adjust inpainting strength to determine how much the model adjusts the contents.

#### Controlnet and T2I adapters

Conditioning based on a depth map, sketch, or line skeleton showing fingers, as opposed to just a text prompt, would help the model with the hand's structure.

In Leonardo.ai, a few Controlnets seem to be available in generation parameters:

[image: Controlnets dropdown]

Using [this](https://unsplash.com/photos/66aKwlV815c) image to get a depth map, the site generated this coherent hand in the same pose:

[image: Image of a woman's hand in the same pose]