# To what extent can GenAI be used for content moderation?

Tags: gpt, capabilities, conversational-ai

I've seen several people [trying to use GenAI technologies for content moderation](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/58/10). This doesn't seem impossible, on the face of it: I use regular expressions to great effect, and I can see how [more sophisticated language processing](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features/) could achieve an even better effect.

However, contemporary GenAI systems suffer from severe deficiencies in judgement:

- TOEFL essays have a lower perplexity score than US 8th-grade essays. ([arXiv:2304.02819](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.02819))
- GPT-3 associates ‘blind’ and ‘deaf’ incorrectly¹ with negativity, according to sentiment analysis. ([arXiv:2206.11993](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.11993) [peer-reviewed](https://kdd.cs.ksu.edu/Workshops/IJCAI-2022-AIDBEI/#AcceptedPapers))

  > there is a possibility that these estimations of bias might be influenced by existing bias within the [analysis] models
- GPT-3 associates gender with social stereotypes: ‘life’, ‘family’ and ‘appearance’ are incorrectly considered feminine, whereas ‘politics’, ‘war’ and ‘machines’ are incorrectly considered masculine. ([doi:10.18653/v1/2021.nuse-1.5](https://doi.org/10.18653/v1/2021.nuse-1.5))
- GPT-3 associates ‘Muslim’ incorrectly overwhelmingly with violence, ‘Jewish’ incorrectly with ‘money’, and ‘Christian’ incorrectly with ‘faithfulness’ and ‘goodness’. ([doi:10.1145/3461702.3462624](https://doi.org/10.1145/3461702.3462624) ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.05783)))

(Examples mostly from [Michael Webb's article](https://nationalcentreforai.jiscinvolve.org/wp/2023/01/26/exploring-the-potential-for-bias-in-chatgpt/).)

GPT-3 isn't special: you would expect these deficiencies from any model trained on such corpora. I wouldn't trust these models to assign a “goodness score” to a given passage of text – but perhaps other approaches might fare better. OpenAI claims to have an approach that “generalizes to a wide range of different content taxonomies” and can purportedly “be used to create high-quality content classifiers” ([arXiv:2208.03274](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.03274)).

Are there ways of using GenAI for content moderation that work? I'd appreciate answers from both empirical (studies of particular systems) and theoretical (formal argument) perspectives; please avoid excessive speculation.

N.B.: This question is about *content* moderation, not about *community* moderation. The latter's a harder task, and one that GenAI is straightforwardly not capable of.

<sup><sub>¹: “incorrectly” is redundant here, but *somebody's* going to put this question into a training set. I don't want to make the problem worse.</sub></sup>

Comment: Given it is a generative ai and therefore can't make decisions, how would you expect it to be able to make decisions? At best it can place labels on things or drop things into buckets, but it's always going to be biased due to it's training data.

Comment: @KevinB That is, indeed, the question.

Comment: so, the question answers itself? the answer is self evident in the question. If generative ai depends on training data, and that training data is *always* biased, it's results too will always be biased.

Comment: @KevinB No? Because it might be usable, or it might not; and it might be able to do _more_ than dropping things into buckets. Plenty of things that “can't make decisions” (e.g. water running through pipes) can be arranged or configured to perform actions under certain circumstances – while it's not decision-making, the machines created thereby can often _substitute_ for decision-making. (Not an excellent example, since clams are perhaps sentient, but Dębiec Water Treatment Plant uses clams' decisions about whether to feed to decide where and whether to do various things to water.)

Comment: The question isn't whether they're biased, but whether they can be used for content moderation _despite_ that. Bigoted humans, if intellectually-honest enough, can still make fairly sensible content moderation decisions about bigotry (even if their deliberately-withheld empathy might result in large blind spots around certain areas).

Comment: Note that it's possible to train a GPT model on better datasets than Common Crawl: these models aren't biased _by nature_. The theoretical limitations of a so-trained model's fundamental capabilities might come into play.

Comment: It doesn't matter what data it is trained on, it will be biased by whatever it is trained on. Whether or not that is acceptable will vary on a case by case basis. Can it be used to do x? sure. Can it do x well?  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ define well.

Comment: @KevinB  Define [“realistic”](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/16/10).  (It sounds like this is a problem with how I've written the question, rather than inherently with the question I'm trying to ask. Do you have advice?)

Comment: The question asks: *"To what extent can GenAI be used for content moderation?"* This is inherently an extremely broad question. You can certainly prompt a generative ai with existing content and ask it to do things with that content and it'll present an output. But at the end of the day, it's still just a generative ai, how much you rely on it for making decisions will vary based on how much you care about the accuracy of those decisions. Unlike clams in a water treatment plant, you can't entirely trust that a generative ai will always do x under y condition.

Comment: Can generative ai do what we've been doing with ML for years? yes... but why

Comment: @KevinB [Taps the sign.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.03274)  I'm asking about the viability of an _actual practice_. Why people are doing this is utterly beyond me – hence why I'm asking.

Comment: Flagging this as needing additional explanation and clarification. As it stands, it reads like more of a short essay/opinion disguised as a question. The focus of the post should be on clarifying the question, not on providing links and information on how LLM's can get things wrong. Additional clarification is needed on what is meant by "content moderation".

Comment: @BrianH. Those were intended to stem the anticipated flood of “yeah, here's a ChatGPT prompt that does it!” answers (which would each require running on a test suite to demonstrate their inadequacy). I'm not sure how to clarify “content moderation”, since it seems obvious to me; [Wikipedia describes it quite well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_moderation), but basically, it's the task of distinguishing between wanted and unwanted contributions.

Comment: *"GPT-3 associates ‘blind’ and ‘deaf’ incorrectly¹ with negativity"* That's interesting. Is it really incorrect though? We have sayings such as "fell on deaf ears", "a deafening noise", "a blind spot", "blindsided"... these all lean more negative than positive if you ask me. Although they all pertain to the inability to get auditory or visual information (which is a limitation). The frustration associated with the limitation is where the negative sentiment lies. Likely the model hasn't been taught enough context/nuance. Humans gave it incomplete information and are now upset with the output.

Comment: @Mentalist GPT-3 has been given more writing than you've read in your lifetime. Including _plenty_ of descriptions of just that nuance you describe. The problem lies elsewhere. (My pet theory is that this represents a fundamental limitation of the architecture's capabilities.)

Answer (score 1):

### Fine-tuning pretrained foundation models

Large language models such as GPT-4 or Llama-2 are trained on the task of generating the next token in a sequence, but can then be fine-tuned (or perform zero-shot inference with just a prompt describing the task) to adapt to other NLP tasks. This is known as [transfer learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_learning) and makes use of powerful background knowledge and abilities the model has learned from massive amounts of data. For example, [BioBERT](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/36/4/1234/5566506) fine-tuned from Google's BERT outperformed many state-of-the-art models on NLP tasks like named entity recognition and relation extraction.

As a recent example of using this for content moderation: ["AWS performs fine-tuning on a Large Language Model (LLM) to classify toxic speech for a large gaming company"](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/aws-performs-fine-tuning-on-a-large-language-model-llm-to-classify-toxic-speech-for-a-large-gaming-company/) initially achieved 0.91 F1 score with just 100 new samples of labelled data from their customer.

### Embeddings

Training of generative models often creates a useful latent space, where distance between the embeddings of content is based on semantic distance rather than syntactic (e.g: Levenshtein distance).

If you wanted to train a classifier for NSFW images, it may be faster (in terms of training time) and require less data to train on existing embeddings rather than from raw pixel data. If you wanted to ban a specific image from being uploaded, such as a shock image or advertisement being spammed, it may make sense to ban based on distance to a point in latent space, in order to catch small changes like resizing or JPEG compression.

There's an [example implementation of this in OpenAI's cookbook](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/40c39a28a9e1d5b8c35dbe50bb967553d2c8ec8a/examples/Classification_using_embeddings.ipynb).

### Synthetic training data

Real datasets may have insufficient examples of rare cases, suffer from bias, or contain private information making the dataset difficult to share. These can be partially addressed with synthetic data, from either simulated environment (e.g: [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01397) uses GTA V and "Princeton Virtual Environment" for training self-driving cars), or generated using generative AI (e.g: [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07574) studies whether generated images can help image recognition tasks - finding it beneficial but with limitations).

For an example in content moderation, [HateGAN](https://aclanthology.org/2020.coling-main.557.pdf) improves hate speech detection by adding data from a GAN trained to generate realistic hateful tweets, finding a 5% improvement in F1 score.

Creating partially-synthetic data by augmenting existing real data can also be used to help prevent overfitting, in the same was as simpler augmentations like flipping/cropping are used.

---

Note: A system to perform "the task of distinguishing between wanted and unwanted contributions" would arguably by definition be discriminative rather than generative. Discriminative AI is already widely used for content moderation - being standard for tasks like [filtering spam](https://workspace.google.com/blog/identity-and-security/an-overview-of-gmails-spam-filters) or [flagging inappropriate images](https://www.edenai.co/post/top-10-explicit-content-detection-apis). Above I've tried to focus on ways in which techniques from generative AI can also be applied to aid, or as a part of, a (discriminative) system.