# How do I get leonardo.ai to add correct, legible text to images?

Tags: image-generation, leonardo.ai

[Leonardo.ai](https://app.leonardo.ai/ai-generations)'s DreamShaper v7 generated this image (click to enlarge):

> A lively modern forum with a (welcoming) atmosphere including many ((people)) with (speech bubbles) containing ((question marks)) above their heads indicating they are (asking each other questions).  Add the words ((GenAI Users)) as a logo in the center of the image using a large font.  Use Stack Exchange's default colors: (sky blue and white).
>
> [image: multiple people (some sitting, some standing) appearing to be having a lively discussion; the background is blue smooth lines and circles, using a Stack-Exchange-like color scheme]

I like it a lot: it has a Stack Exchange question and answer vibe.  Perhaps unsurprisingly, it didn't write "GenAI Users" correctly, and instead wrote "QEN!".  Hence...

**Question**: How do I get leonardo.ai to add correct, legible text to images?

Comment: Open up the output in an image editor and add the text manually.

Comment: Admittedly, that is an option in this case, but I'm hoping to do this more generally, so maybe something like [this](https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/53/26) (for limbs) is possible.

Comment: In general, I only know of one method that's possibly better than doing it all manually: You can use the technique of inpainting/controlnets/T2I adapters mentioned in your linked post.

Specifically, edit your text onto a base generation that you like. Your edit can be fast and sloppy. Then, use a controlnet, say canny edge detection or scribble, and inpaint/img2img the flaws of your edit away. Most AI may not yet be capable of generating coherent text, but I find that with a controlnet, they can preserve it fairly well.

Answer (score 3):

**ControlNets** and **T2I adapters** both allow you to condition generation on some kind of image input rather than just a text prompt. Using edges should work best for maintaining the shape of text.

In Leonardo.ai you can select a ControlNet in the generation parameters and upload an image used to determine edges:

[image: ControlNet generation options]

Adjusting "ControlNet Weight" will determine how close it'll stick to the edges of the uploaded image.

Template used:

[image: Black on white text example]

Result when using with a prompt of "Text written in stone":

[image: Generated stone text]