# How to generate exact word(s) in generated image?

Tags: prompt-design, image-generation, stable-diffusion, text-to-image, image

I want to design a prompt where I already have the main thing in the image fixed, but I need to have a text included in the image with exact word(s) I put in there. For example, this is my prompt.

> a flying bird, text "Bird" in the background

The result only generates a flying bird. No text in the image, let alone the exact word.

How to generate exact word(s) in generated image?

I am using [this tool](https://replicate.com/stability-ai/stable-diffusion).

Comment: Note this question about leonardo.ai: [How do I get leonardo.ai to add correct, legible text to images?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/165/26).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ControlNets** and **T2I adapters** both allow you to condition generation on some kind of image input rather than just a text prompt. Best option for exact text would likely be the ControlNet or T2I adapter for edges:

- [Canny ControlNet (SD 1.5)](https://huggingface.co/lllyasviel/ControlNet/blob/main/models/control_sd15_canny.pth)
- [Canny T2I adapter (SD 1.5)](https://huggingface.co/TencentARC/T2I-Adapter/blob/main/models/t2iadapter_canny_sd15v2.pth)
- [Canny ControlNet (SD XL)](https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/control-lora/blob/main/control-LoRAs-rank256/control-lora-canny-rank256.safetensors) + [ComfyUI workflow](https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/control-lora/blob/main/comfy-control-LoRA-workflows/control-lora-canny-basic_example.json)

These are available for [Stable Diffusion 1.5](https://huggingface.co/runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5/blob/main/v1-5-pruned-emaonly.ckpt), which is used by the linked web demo, and also [Stable Diffusion XL](https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0). You could use the ControlNet/T2I adapter scripts in their repos, but I'd recommend using [ComfyUI](https://github.com/comfyanonymous/ComfyUI) - or [Automatic1111's web UI](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui) with its [ControlNet extension](https://github.com/Mikubill/sd-webui-controlnet).

You can first generate an image of a bird as normal:

[image: Bird]
(image contains ComfyUI workflow graph metadata - can be downloaded and dragged into the UI)

Then filter it with a canny edge detector. Below I used the "Image Canny Filter" from [WAS Node Suite](https://github.com/WASasquatch/was-node-suite-comfyui), but any method should work:

[image: Bird canny edges]
(image contains ComfyUI workflow graph metadata)

Repeat for some text "Bird"

[image: "Bird" text canny edges]

Combine the two:

[image: Combined canny edges]

Then, as shown below, feed this alongside the text prompt into the ControlNet/T2I Adapter to adjust the conditioning:

[image: ComfyUI workflow]

Result:

[image: Generated image of bird flying in front of "Bird" text]
(image contains ComfyUI workflow graph metadata)

Comment: This feels like doing the photoshop work to me. I'll wait for some time to see if anyone can answer with just prompt; otherwise, I will accept this answer later.