# How to generate the images either by Dall E model or Azure OpenAI services without getting bad or disformed human faces

Tags: llm, image-generation, text-to-image, fine-tuning, dall-e

I was trying to generate images using the Dall E model, the model is getting all the inputs of exactly from the prompt but the image generated is full of disformed faces, hands and legs after a few attempts of variations the image is getting fixed but

1. not upto expected
2. have to try multiple times
3. tokens are limited
   Is there any other way to overcome this without changing the model itself?
   Thanks in Advance!
   [image: dalle image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I effectively create a prompt to generate realistic limbs and fingers using Leonardo.ai?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-can-i-effectively-create-a-prompt-to-generate-realistic-limbs-and-fingers-us)

Answer (score 1):

OpenAI's DALL-E web interface allows for **inpainting**. Once you're happy with the rest of the image, you could focus solely on iterating the faces or areas with extra limbs.

Since the faces aren't touching each other, it should also be fairly easy to take the best left face from one inpainted image and the best right face from another inpainted image, rather than needing both to be good in the same result.

Initial text-to-image generation:

[image: Two people with horrifying-looking faces running. I dare not consider what they are running from.]

Inpainting mask:

[image: Inpainting]

The result: maybe a slight improvement?

[image: Still pretty horrifying.]

---

DALL-E generally handles faces and hands better at a large scale. The best option, without using other models, may be to zoom in on the person's face, upload that to DALL-E for inpainting, then paste the result back onto the original image:

[image: Inpainting, zoomed into man's face]

Result (only changed man's face):

[image]

Comment: Thanks I need to try this out but this inpainting option available in the api services as well? as it need to be done in a processed system.

Comment: @Swesh Looks like inpainting is available through the API too, yep: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/images/edits